# Django Delete OneToOneField

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm creating a Django web-app. I have an app named `vote`. I want to "register" this app via a OneToOne-Relationship to other apps. For example, I have an article app and I want to "register" vote:

```
vote = models.OneToOneField(Vote, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
```

I changed the save method on article:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.vote = Vote.objects.create()
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here's the problem:
I want the vote to be deleted when I delete article but that doesn't work.
When I delete article only article will be deleted and vote still exists.

Comment: How you delete an article object? give an example.

Comment: I think overriding the `save(..)` to create a vote is not a good idea in the first place for two reasons (a) the `save` function can be omitted (for example in case of a `bulk_create`), and (b) here you create a new *vote* each time you call `.save()` (so updating will result in creating a new vote as  well).

Comment: @ShafikurRahman I delete article objects via django admin.

Comment: That being said, it looks as if you want to have two models that actually are a single entity. So perhaps it is better to "merge" the two models, and set the references correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct behavior. you want to delete an article and want its votes to be deleted. so you should put your relation(One to One) on the `Vote` model, not the article. So replace:

```
vote = models.OneToOneField(Vote, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
```

To:

```
article = models.OneToOneField(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

But on the vote model.

> Note that: do not use default and null on this case.

Also, you can read this [Link](https://medium.com/@ajrbyers/django-fk-on-delete-defaults-to-cascade-1c1506aae7c7) to understand where to put a relation and how cascade will delete it.

Comment: Thanks but I want to add vote to multiple apps. I have apps like article, riddle and poll and I want to add to all of these a vote possibility.

Comment: In that case, you have two options: inherit base vote to different classes and in each add the proper relation OR override `delete` in Django admin and delete in manually.